# How do you read in kaggle data?

Tags: kaggle

I am running the python code from lesson 3 of the fast ai course. However, I'm receiving a “syntax” error. Any pointers, please?

```
! mkdir -p ~/.kaggle/
! mv kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/


! mkdir %userprofile%.kaggle
! move kaggle.json %userprofile%.kaggle
```

Cheers.

Comment: Can you provide the full code you are trying to run? We can't know what the syntax error is if we can't see the code.

Comment: I was following the code here: https://github.com/fastai/course-v3/blob/master/nbs/dl1/lesson3-planet.ipynb

Comment: Hopefully it’s obvious where the code is from, fourth box down